# Java / Azure / Jni4Net / dll / Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-web-app-service, jni4net

I have recently deployed my java spring boot app to the Azure app services. Everything is ok until I try to instantiate service class from the third party DLL rolled up in the spring boot up with jni4net (this works perfectly  when deployed to standard win server).

```
Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom - works ok
```

in the moment I try to create new instance of some object from DLL library I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [xxx.Calculation]: Factory method 'XXXInitializator' threw exception; nested exception is System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
```

Obviously some kind of permission issue. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't changed the service logon user. You can do it from service control manager by right-clicking the service and go to the Logon tab. Then add user as Service Logon User.